# Python script. Excel таблицу перевести в html

Tags: html, python, excel

Доброго время суток,

не могли бы помочь?

Нужно вывести столбцы с A11 и J11 в html. Получилось вывести, но выводится все подряд и без таблицы.

HTML file: https://1drv.ms/x/s!ApkW2_Ur4r15g0R6MU4DDLow9faS

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook('fruits.xlsx')
ws = workbook.get_active_sheet()

html_data = """
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        XLSX to HTML 
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>
        XLSX to HTML
        </h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
             <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
"""
ws_range = ws['A11:J12']

for row in ws_range:
    html_data += "<tr>"
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value is None:
            html_data += "<td>" + ' ' + "<td>"
        else:
            html_data += "<td>" + str(cell.value) + "<td>"
    html_data += "<tr>"
html_data += "<table>";"<body>";"<html>"

with open("fruits.html", "w") as html_fil:
    html_fil.write(html_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что то, что Вы делаете в цикле, а именно

```
html_data += "<td>" + ' ' + "</td>"
```

не формирует таблицу там, где Вы ее ожидаете, а добавляет данные в конец строки html_data, т.е. уже после тега `</html>`. Вероятно, нужно первоначальное объявление html_data закончить после тега `<table>`, потом в цикле добавлять строки (только в Вашем примере, когда после `<td>` добавляет второй раз `<tr>` - надо прописать закрывающий тег (`</tr>`). А потом уже, после добавления всех строк, добавлять, опять же, закрывающие теги `</table></body></html>`